# Close div when I click on any button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a few tooltips on an image. I want to slide open a div (with text) if a tooltip is clicked. This is working fine using the code below.

The part I can't figure out: I also want to close any open "tooltip_content" if I press any of the tooltips.

I did build this before (with display/hide) but am out of ideas how to do it using a slide-effect.

```
<div class="tooltip">
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="tooltip_content">Text</div>
</div>

$(".tooltip .inner").click(function(){
  $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add one more line :

```js
$(".tooltip .inner").click(function() {
    $('.tooltip_content:visible').not($(this).next()).slideUp();
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.tooltip_content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tooltip">
  <div class="inner">inner1</div>
  <div class="tooltip_content">Text1</div>
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
  <div class="inner">inner2</div>
  <div class="tooltip_content">Text2</div>
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
  <div class="inner">inner3</div>
  <div class="tooltip_content">Text3</div>
</div>
```

The jQuery object `$('.tooltip_content:visible')` will look for the visible `tooltip_content` div and if it finds one or more, it will slide them up but excluding the current objects next item with `.not($(this).next())`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This does close the open content-block fine with any of the closed tooltips, however if I click on the tooltip that has the open content, the content closes and opens again right away.

Comment: This doesn't open the tooltips anymore if all of them are closed... 

I'm able to open a div if all closed or close an open tooltip when I click on it or close a tooltip by clicking on another. Just getting all those effects together is makin me mad ;-)

Comment: @TheGmo Yes you were right! just added a demo see if that is what you want.

Comment: That's exactly it! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(".tooltip_content").click(function(){
  $('.tooltip_content:visible').slideToggle();
});
```

use this code will make your effect.